# Can't get font family to show on live website

Tags: html, css, fonts

So, I'm using a font-face webkit from fontsquirrel and I've put the stylesheet and all fonts in a folder called "Fonts" which is contained in my HTML folder with my Index.html file. I'm using Dreamweaver and iPage and I've put the new files and synched them, but they aren't showing on other computers on the live page like they should. They work in my preview obviously. Here is my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Fonts/stylesheet.css" />
```

Comment: What's the contents of `stylesheet.css`?

Comment: Sorry, had to run out. I will be back to my computer soon and post contents. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Fonts/Stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
```

And are you using css to implement the tag, for example:

```
<style>
p {font-family: 'stylesheet', sans-serif;}
</style>
```

Is it possible to edit out the font tag in iPage and replace it with a text tag like

```
 <p></p>
```

because

```
 <font face="stylesheet"></font>
```

is deprecated, but may still work in preview mode.